# CakePHP: Need DB table for every controller?

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, cakephp-1.2

I'm a newbie to CakePHP but got strange error. I'm just testing it, how to implement many functions and got strange error. I have created a controller called `about` and got the following error:

```
Error:  Database table abouts for model About was not found.
```

Does CakePHP require to have DB table for every single controller?

`var $useTable = false;` is not working.

I am using CakePHP 1.2.5

Answer (score -4, accepted):

you should add about method to your main application controller

Comment: A model doesn't need a table. You can implement a mock model and even a model that communicates through REST APIs to other websites.

Comment: @runge, thanks for letting me know, I just used KohanaPHP before when I was able to create controller without model, but quit it due to lack of documentation.

@Michael Andresson: Your method is working too, then no need to create model.

@Tor Valamo: Thanks! :)

Comment: I think this cannot be the accepted answer, since it's incorrect in the CakePHP context. You can indeed have a controller without having table, as @Johannes pointed out

Answer (score 13):

Try using this in your controller

```
var $uses = array();
```

The `$usesTable = false` idiom is used **in models** that don't have associated tables.